# Is every semisimple element of a Borel subalgebra contained in a Cartan subalebra of the Borel subalgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$), $\mathfrak{b}$ a Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $L$ a semisimple element contained in $\mathfrak{b}$.

I know that $L$ is contained in a Cartan subalgebra (CSA) of $\mathfrak{g}$. Is it true that $L$ is contained in a CSA of $\mathfrak{b}$? If so, why?

Comment: there's a typo in your title

Comment: This $\mathfrak{g}$ is its own commutator subalgebra, so it is ${\rm{Lie}}(G)$ for a connected linear algebraic group $G$ (as over any field of char. 0); see Cor. 7.9 in Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups*.  This $G$ has trivial radical since its Lie algebra has no nonzero solvable Lie ideal, so $G$ is semisimple. Lie algebras of Borel subgroups (resp. maximal tori) of $G$ are the Borel subalgebras (resp. CSA's) of $\mathfrak{g}$ by structure theory, so $L$ is tangent to a Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$. Apply 11.8 in Borel to $B$ to find a maximal torus of $B$ to which $L$ is tangent.

Comment: I'd add to nfdc23's succinct comment two points:  1) From older work of Grothendieck, updated in a 1968 paper by Borel-Springer in *Tohoku Math.  J.*, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the union of its Borel subalgebras and thus any semisimple element does lie in at least one of them; 2) suitably reworded, the question and answer apply equally well to the Lie algebra of a semisimple group in arbitrary characteristic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another answer, using only Lie algebra theory. After applying ${\rm ad}_{\mathfrak{g}}$ we can assume that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple subalgebra of some $\mathfrak{gl}_k(V)$. As such, $\mathfrak{g}$ is almost algebraic, as defined in Jacobson's book, page 98 (called "decomposable" in the English translation of Bourbaki, Lie VII, or "scindable" in the original French version), i.e., it contains the semisimple and nilpotent components of all its elements. The Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ is almost algebraic too. This follows for example from Bourbaki, Lie VII, section 5.2, Cor 1: The almost algebraic envelope $e(\mathfrak{b})$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ is a solvable subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ because $\mathfrak{g}$ is almost algebraic, hence equals $\mathfrak{b}$, because $\mathfrak{b}$ is a maximal solvable subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Hence $\mathfrak{b}$ is an almost algebraic subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_k(V)$.

The element $L$ is semisimple. It is therefore contained in an abelian subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ consisting of semisimple elements (called a toral subalgebra in Humphreys' book). By reasons of dimensions we can assume that $\mathfrak{t}$ is a maximal such subalgebra. Now Bourbaki, Lie VII, section 5.3, Proposition 6 says that the centralizer $\mathfrak{c}$ of $\mathfrak{t}$ in $\mathfrak{b}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{b}$. Since $\mathfrak{t}$ is abelian, we have $\mathfrak{c} \supset \mathfrak{t} \ni L$.